# Using a beyond Compare script To Get the total files and lines of code in a directory

Tags: scripting, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Trying to get the current number of lines in a directory 
Current command:

```
load "C:\dir" " "
expand all
TEXT-REPORT layout:statistics output-to:"BCREPORT.csv"
```

It gives me a report that has"ï»¿" in the upper-left corner.

I might be using the wrong type of report. I'll try a folder report at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ï»¿` is the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

I guess with *the upper-right corner* you mean the begin of the document text. So there is no wrong *type of report* only a flag for the encoding of the report content.

See also http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_filereportencoding (Attention, belongs to old version BC2):

> WHAT CHARACTER ENCODING DOES BEYOND COMPARE SAVE REPORT FILES IN?
>
> Beyond Compare's File Differences Report command generates report files (plain text) in the same character encoding as the left side file.
>
> For example, if the left side file is ANSI, the report generated will be ANSI.  If the left side file is UTF-8, the report will be generated in UTF-8.

So if your compared file on the left side is ANSI, then the report would also be ANSI (if there was no change since version BC2))

Comment: Sorry I meant left. Got them all switched up. And yes.

Comment: I should be more clear and I only get "ï»¿" in the upper corner and the rest of report is blank...

Comment: When I try your `load "C:\dir" " "` then I get an error because of the empty dir to compare. Is the 2nd `" "` really an empty dir in your script?

Comment: yup... It is empty... I was trying mimic what the GUI does with a script.